# How to tackle pointwise minimum constraint?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

I have an optimization problem with a constraint of the following form:

\begin{align}
\inf_y\quad &J(y)\\
\mbox{s.t.}\quad & y\in\mathcal{Y}\\
&\min_{j}a_j^\top y+b_j\leq \delta
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{Y}$ is a convex set. I understand that the second constraint is a nonconvex one. But is there no way to tackle it without using mixed integer formulation?

One way I thought of was using the epigraph form, which is incorrect in this case, as it results in the following:

\begin{align}
\inf_y\quad &J(y)\\
\mbox{s.t.}\quad & y\in\mathcal{Y}\\
&t\leq \delta\\
&a_j^\top y+b_j\geq t,\;\forall j
\end{align}

I would appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: No, not possible. The $\min$ constraint is nonconvex and requires a MILP representation, or some other fundamentally nonconvex strategy.

Comment: Thank you very much!